# Website doesn't load portfolio content on mobile

Tags: wordpress, responsiveness

I just made a website using a Wordpress theme and it all works good on desktop computers. However, while the site initially loads normally on my phone (I'm using iPhone 6 with iOS9, but the problem is the same on Android phones too, I tried two), once I click on the portfolio item, it loads a blank page (header and footer only).

When I tap on the address bar, I notice that it never went to the right link at first place (the portfolio item link), it just shows the homepage link and there is no content.

I managed to fix the problem by entering the external URL in portfolio item options. It was still internal link from the site but I made the link open the new tab (if it doesn't open new tab, the problem stays the same). However, if I choose to go back to the homepage from that link (the portfolio item link), the homepage is blank, there is only header and footer so the problem returns again.

Just so you know, the first portfolio item contains the external link outside the Wordpress and that one opens normally.

What is wrong with the mobile site?

The site URL is: http://svenharambasic.com

The screenshot is attached. Thank you!

P.S. There are also google ads showing, I never encountered that before, but I'll work on that once this is solved.

[image: this is how the page looks like when I open the portfolio item]

Answer (score 1):

I only see a white screen upon clicking any of the homepage portfolio image links (except for the first link which goes to an external site in a new tab) on desktop and on mobile actually. There is a `content_inner` class with inline styling setting `visibility:hidden`.

It's unclear to me why it's doing that- maybe to remove focus from the body and draw focus towards something that is supposed to appear in the foreground but does not? If I remove `visibility:hidden` from the element in the browser, I see a series of additional images appear, which seems to me to be more an expected behavior. Are we on the right track?

Comment: it works normally to me on two desktop computers, it just takes a little bit of time to load, on mobile it never loads... in each portfolio link there should be a series of large images one above another so i think that's the right track, yes

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this, it was the setting in the theme options; I had to disable grid lines... I can't say I truly understand why, but it worked!